# save a plot as a png in gnuplot and C

Tags: c, plot, gnuplot

I have been able to use gnuplot to plot graphs as I run my program, but now I want to write the graphs to files. The following code opens a plot and creates a png, but the png does not open (Gimp says it is corrupted). Admittedly I don't really understand the code I've written, because it's taken from snippets online. Does anyone know what's wrong? All I want to do is be able to save my scatter graph as a png.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gnuplot_i.h"
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 double average_distance[5] = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4};
 double x_coord[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 gnuplot_ctrl* h1 = gnuplot_init();
 gnuplot_setstyle(h1, "points");
 gnuplot_cmd(h1, "set output 'test-plot-1.png'");
 gnuplot_plot_xy(h1, x_coord, average_distance, 5, "plot");
 gnuplot_cmd(h1,"set terminal x11" );
 sleep(400);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `set terminal png` instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i've made that change but i still can't open the png file :(

Comment: ok, i figured it out. i had to add set terminal png before the set output command

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) (GPL plotting library) which can native export to PNG/EPS/SVG/... and can do it even in console (i.e. without X) ?